# Portable way to `strip` during `install` while cross-compiling

Tags: cross-compiling, binutils, gnu-coreutils

When `install -s` is run, it calls `strip` program as is, resulting in host-provided version of this program to be run, which breaks cross-compilation scenarios where target-specific version of `strip` must be called. To achieve such a goal, host-specific techniques need to be used, as far as I can see:

- [GNU install](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/install.1.html) accepts `--strip-program` parameter to specify the binary path;
- [BSD install](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=install) relies on `STRIPBIN` environment variable.

Why do they all use completely different approaches for the same very basic tasks? Why doesn't either of them use `STRIP` environment variable which is usually employed in *Makefile*s? Or am I missing some other, uniform method for this task?